# How to make type conversion in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I'm have the following code in the file main.hs:

```
teste :: Integral a => a -> a
teste n = truncate (sqrt n) + mod n 2
```

and i'm getting the following error from ghci when I try to load it:

```
Prelude> :l main.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )

main.hs:12:11:
    Could not deduce (RealFrac a) arising from a use of ‘truncate’
    from the context (Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for teste :: Integral a => a -> a
      at main.hs:11:10-29
    Possible fix:
      add (RealFrac a) to the context of
        the type signature for teste :: Integral a => a -> a
    In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘truncate (sqrt n)’
    In the expression: truncate (sqrt n) + mod n 2
    In an equation for ‘teste’: teste n = truncate (sqrt n) + mod n 2

main.hs:12:21:
    Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    from the context (Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for teste :: Integral a => a -> a
      at main.hs:11:10-29
    Possible fix:
      add (Floating a) to the context of
        the type signature for teste :: Integral a => a -> a
    In the first argument of ‘truncate’, namely ‘(sqrt n)’
    In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘truncate (sqrt n)’
    In the expression: truncate (sqrt n) + mod n 2
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

but when I run the same code in the interective mode, it works fine:

```
Prelude> truncate (sqrt 5) + mod 5 2
3
```

Comment: That is because the `n` in your `teste` has one type, whereas in your `ghci`, the `5` in `sqrt` and `5` in `mod` have a different type.

Comment: The error message gives you two correct hints "add (RealFrac a) to the context of..."  and "add (Floating a) to the context of". If you write down the function in GHCI and let it infer the type, you'll have exactly that: `(Floating a, Integral a, RealFrac a) => a -> a`

Comment: @EliKorvigo: someting that is both `Floating` and `Integral` is strictly speaking possible in *Haskell*, but conceptually it does not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I know. I was just pointing out, that the compiler gave two important hints as to why the function (as it is) does not compile with type signature `Integral a => a -> a`

Answer (score 5):

In your call `truncate (sqrt 5) + mod 5 2`, the `5`s have different types. Indeed the `5` in the `sqrt 5` should have as type `Floating a => a`, whereas the `5` in `mod 5 2` has type `Integral b => b`. Although it is, strictly speaking possible to construct a type in Haskell that is a member of both type families, conceptually it is *odd* that a type is both `Integral` and `Floating`, it would also only be applicable to such types, making it less useful. We thus could change the signature to:

```
teste :: (Integral a, Floating a, RealFrac a) => a -> a
teste n = truncate (sqrt n) + mod n 2
```

but as said before, this is not very *useful*.

You can use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) here to convert from an `Integral` type to any `Num` type, like:

```
teste :: Integral a => a -> a
teste n = truncate (sqrt (fromIntegral n)) + mod n 2
```

For example:

```
Prelude> teste 5
3
```